# Get grid points of a specific plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a map using matplotlib. I want the coordinates of all grid points within the map and neglect all the grid points outside the map. Is there any method which can be used directly in this? Intertools is giving all the grid points but i want only the points within the map.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pt
import itertools
pt.set_xticks(np.arange(65,100,.75))
pt.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,.75))
gridpoints = list( itertools.product(xticks, yticks) )
print gridpoints
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "map", as your code doesn't plot anything.

Comment: I have the coordinates of indian map which i am plotting here. Sorry for not specifying about the coordinates.  these coordinates are read from a file and then a plot is plotted.

Comment: you just need to say `pt.set_xlim( max(xvariable), min(xvariable) )` and the same for the `y-axis`

Comment: Do you mean you want all the grid points inside the irregular shape defined by another set of points? Is this second set of points always on the grid-lines, or is it irregular?

Comment: Also: generally, this problem is hard -- how to find a point in a polygon, when the polygon may be not convex, or not simply connected. There are a lot of questions in the Google and other map tools tags working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I'll venture a guess. If you're trying to get all of the grid line intersections on a plot you might try something like this:

```
def getGridPoints(ax):
    xticks = ax.get_xticks()
    yticks = ax.get_yticks()
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xbound()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ybound()

    return list( itertools.product( [x for x in xticks if x>xmin and x<xmax],
                                    [y for y in yticks if y>ymin and y<ymax]))
```

Comment: what does ax here? I have taken ax=plt.figure().gca(). Is it correct?

Comment: ax is a 'matplotlib.axes' object ([link](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)). I usually use the idiom `fig,ax = plt.subplots()`, but `gca()` works too.